# How to stop WordPress from removing & from URL?

Tags: permalinks, urls, bug-tracking

So I have a URL which has a tracking link applied to the end. For some reason WordPress is removing the `&` which is causing the tracking to fail. You can see the URL example here:

> http://www.domain.co.uk/internalpage/?&mkwid=smWfvaLGf_dm

When you go through this, you then get **redirected** in a way to:

> http://www.domain.co.uk/internalpage/?mkwid=smWfvaLGf_dm

Note the `&` has been removed. Also, this only happens on internal pages. Does anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: Just curious, why do you need the extra & part and what tracking is failing? I guess I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Essential it is best practice to keep in the "&" as Marin (PPC Optimisation Software) builds their urls (The tracking element) a certain way. The tracking is failing because with the "&" being removed it is also stripping out the gclid (Google Analytics Click ID) which means that Google cannot tell if the traffic is Paid Search, therefore allocates it as "Direct" which is messing up GA essentially.

Comment: It looks like this replacement takes place in the huge `redirect_canonical()` callback, where it removes only the first `&` so `?&a=1&b=2` is redirected to `?a=1&b=2`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the *why* part:

[This part](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/72c6f7f86f133a0d5ec669526eeb29ca024c0c19/wp-includes/canonical.php#L358-L359) of the `redirect_canonical()` is removing the leading `&` in the *redirect query* part:

```
// tack on any additional query vars
$redirect['query'] = preg_replace( '#^\??&*?#', '', $redirect['query'] );
```

Example:

```
example.tld/?&a=1&b=2&c=3
```

is redirected to

```
example.tld/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

If you must have the leading `&` you might try to adjust it through the `redirect_canonical` filter:

```
/**
 * Filter the canonical redirect URL.
 *
 * Returning false to this filter will cancel the redirect.
 *
 * @since 2.3.0
 *
 * @param string $redirect_url  The redirect URL.
 * @param string $requested_url The requested URL.
 */
$redirect_url = apply_filters( 'redirect_canonical', $redirect_url, $requested_url );
```

Comment: OK this seems very interesting! Do you know how I would adjust the redirect_canonical in order to keep my leading "&" ? Also with every core wordpress update this change would get removed right?

I only ask because there must be a better solution from Marin if this is the case. As if this is the way WordPress is built, there must be a reason. Thanks for the above :)

Comment: Hey - so I have found a semi-solution. The reason why Marin needs the "&" is because it doesn't know where in the tracking parameter it is going to be placed. So say we have other tracking ID's like the below:

example.tld/?&a=1&other_tracking&marin_tracking

In order not to break it, it always attaches the "&" otherwise it might end up like this

example.tld/?&a=1&other_trackingmarin_tracking

So if Marin is first in the URL we can remove the "&" from being placed in which fixes this. However it does mean it is open to breaking in the order of the tracking is changed.

Comment: Don't modify the core files. Do it through the filter within your custom plugin. You could try to see if the diff of `$redirect_url` and `$requested_url`  is only `&` and then return false to stop the redirection. @Coder_2016

Comment: If you do have another solution that would be great though - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use here rawurlencode() function. First pass "?&mkwid=smWfvaLGf_dm" this url into the function then you will get "%3F%26mkwid%3DsmWfvaLGf_dm" encoded value.

Now go on the functions.php and put this code there (But this code will run on every call of you site)

```
//for accessing current url
$accessUrl = get_site_url() .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$pos = strpos($accessUrl, "%");
if ($pos !== false) 
{
    $accessString = rawurldecode($accessUrl);
    wp_redirect($accessString);
    exit();
}
```

I feel this will help you.
Thanks

Comment: With this solution though, do I have to enter in the URL in the Raw URL encode function each time? I can't use this because there are 100's of different tracking parameters so I would have to store each of these.

A live example can be seen here on WordPress actually: https://wordpress.org/showcase/?&mkwid=smWfvaLGf_dm